# Spring AOP: How to determine if method threw an exception using @After?

Tags: spring, spring-aop

Spring [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-advice-after-finally) say:

> After advice must be prepared to handle both normal and exception
>   return conditions.

```
@After("com.xyz.myapp.SystemArchitecture.dataAccessOperation()")
public void doReleaseLock() {
    // ...
}
```

I'm interested in knowing whether `dataAccessOperation` completed normally or with an exception. Unfortunately, the above code snippet is in the run for the most useless documentation ever produced. I understand that I can use `AfterReturning` and `AfterThrowing` separately, or even `Around`, but that's not the point. Since `After` exists, I should be able to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the documentation wants to say is that your `@After` advice should do a valid thing no matter whether an exception was thrown or not. It does not mean you can determine it from the advice. If different things should be done,

- either use `@AfterReturning` vs. `@AfterThrowing` if the control flow is not to be touched and no exception is to be handled by your advices,
- or use an `@Around` advice if you want to actually catch and handle thrown exceptions and/or modify method parameters before call or the return value after the call or skip method execution altogether.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you’re saying it’s not possible to retrieve the exception or the return value from within `After`.  The rest of your answer about `After*` or `Around` is already mentioned in my question.

Comment: You may have _mentioned_ it, but I _explained_ it for everyone to understand when to use which. Remember, on SO we are asking and answering in public, others also read questions and answers. If you just look at the parameters defined for the three `@After*` annotations, you see that indeed it is like you said and like I explained.