# Global Exception Handling via Spring Advice In a MQ based Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, exception, spring-aop

I've a MQ Spring Boot PaaS application where I need to implement exception handling via a common exception handler class (GlobalExceptionHandler). My PaaS application receives message from a source queue, perform some database operations via spring jpa and write the response back to a destination queue.

I need to handle all the database RuntimeException, custom business exceptions and other checked exceptions via GlobalExceptionHandler class.

My GlobalExceptionHandler will have handlers (method) defined for every exception. In my handler, I will be logging the exception first and then I will be creating a [error code, desc] and then I need to return it back to main flow.

I do not have any controller in my application. So I think, I can't use @ControllerAdvice. Currently I'm using spring AOP @AfterThrowing as below but I'm not able to return the [code, desc] from handlers.

```
@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* com.abc.xyz.service..*(..)) ", 
throwing = "dataNotFoundException")
    public void handleDataNotFoundException(DataNotFoundException dataNotFoundException) {
       LOGGER.info("Info : " + dataNotFoundException.getMessage());
       // code, desc need to create here and send it back to calling place.
       // I need to change the return type here from void.
    }
```

Can anyone please guide me in implementing exception handling here.

Answer (score 0):

As I explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48787878/1082681), `@AfterThrowing` cannot modify return values or otherwise change the execution flow of your epplication. You cannot even catch the exception there. You need to use an `@Around` advice instead.

I suggest you read some documentation first and then ask more follow-up questions.